# ROS Intel Realsense how to process data with PCL

Tags: ros, ros-pcl, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Currently i a trying to detect object using a Intel realsense D415 camera.
I got the camera running and it can publish /camera/depth/color/points.
My question is how to process this data to detect the object?

I understand that it possible to use PCL to process point cloud data and i think it may by possible to used it for my application.
However i have no idea how to use PCL or how to use PCL with ROS.

Any tips, advises, examples or suggestions are welcome.

I run the system on on a ubuntu 16.04 LTS and ROS kinetic.
The package i got working are the realsens2_camera and pcl_ros.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/316701/ros-intel-realsense-how-to-process-data-with-pcl/) by [Kluun](https://answers.ros.org/users/37797/kluun/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2019-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I found a way to process the Intel Realsense data with PCL.
First made a subscriber for the /camera/depth/color/points.
I translate the sensor_msgs::Pointcloud2  to pcl::PCLPointCloud2::Ptr.
Than i uses the PCL functions to process the point cloud and at the end i translate it back to sensor_msgs::Pointcloud2, so i can publish it and see it with RVIZ.

---

Originally posted by [Kluun](https://answers.ros.org/users/37797/kluun/) with karma: 15 on 2019-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0